# What are the advantages of using @Html.DisplayFor rather than @item?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreach

What is the advantage of using lets say

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Example)
```

rather than

```
@item.Example
```

in a table setting with a **@foreach(var item in Model)**?

They seem very similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate: [When should I use Html.Displayfor in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465376/when-should-i-use-html-displayfor-in-mvc)

Summary:

```
@* Can be used with a DisplayTemplate for extended displaying for the Type. *@
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Example)

@* Only displays a HTML encoded (to better protect against XSS attack) string representation of the value. *@
@item.Example
```