# Displaying data in a view returned from a controller

Tags: c#, razor

I am trying to write a simple web application which displays certain details dependent on which ID is picked from a select list.

I can get the data from the database using the following:

Class:

```
namespace InterviewTest.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
[Table("Widget")]

        public partial class Widget
        {
            public int WidgetID { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(50)]
            public string WidgetName { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public string WidgetDescription { get; set; }

            public int WidgetColourID { get; set; }
        }

}
```

Controller:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using InterviewTest.Models;

namespace InterviewTest.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        WidgetConn db = new WidgetConn();

        public virtual ActionResult Index(Widget widget)
        {


            var widgets =
                (from w in db.Widgets
                 where w.WidgetID == 1
                 select new
                    {
                     WidgetName = w.WidgetName,
                     WidgetDescription = w.WidgetDescription,
                     WidgetColourID = w.WidgetColourID
                    }).ToList();

            var data = widgets[0];

            return View(data);
        }
    }
}
```

The data returned in 'data' is returned as:

WidgetID 1
WidgetDescription Test
WidgetColourID 1

Test View:

```
@model InterviewTest.Models.Widget
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "test";
}

<h2>test</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Widget</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WidgetName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.WidgetName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WidgetDescription)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.WidgetDescription)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WidgetColourID)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.WidgetColourID)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.WidgetID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

When I try to us @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WidgetName) to display the data returned I get the error:

htmlhelper does not contain a definition for DisplayNameFor and no extension method DisplayNameFor accepting a first argument of type 'HTMLHelper' could be found. Are you missing an assembley or reference?

I read that I should have 'using System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper;' however this appears to be a namespace so cannot be used in this way. Changing my namespace means I can no longer access this class.

I also read that System.Web.Mvc.Html should containt the 'HtmlHelper' but using this has not resolved my issue.

My questions are:

1: Should I be using @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WidgetName) with a .cshtml file or is there another way to access the data?

2: If the way I am trying to access the data is correct, how/where do I add the namespace so I can access the HtmlHelper namespace.

3: If the the way I am trying to access the data is NOT correct for a .cshtml file please could someone point me to some documentation I could read?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try scaffolding?, your views

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have previously use scaffolding but I was trying to do it manually this time to get a better understanding of how everything works.

I would ideally like to be able to do what scaffolding/EF does but manually as I am trying to learn and understand what is going on when the code is written and what happens when I run it.

Comment: try reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465376/when-should-i-use-html-displayfor-in-mvc , and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365633/what-is-the-html-displayfor-syntax-for

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are selecting the data as an unknown type. Instead of unknown, specify its type. So please replace your code as shown below.

```
 public virtual ActionResult Index(Widget widget)
        {
            IEnumerable<Widget> widgets =
                (from w in db.Widgets
                 where w.WidgetID == 1
                 select new Widget 
                    {
                     WidgetName = w.WidgetName,
                     WidgetDescription = w.WidgetDescription,
                     WidgetColourID = w.WidgetColourID
                    }).ToList();

            var data = (widgets!=null && widgets.length>0)? widgets[0]: null;

            return View(data);
        }
```