# How to fetch just the date from DateTime Entity while iterating an Entity Framework Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to fetch just the date from the DateTime Entity in the View which I created in the Models. But instead it shows the whole DateTime Format

I added an Annotation [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")], but the issue remains.

```
//Models: 
 [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }


//Adding Migration, it processed it as: 
BirthDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false)


//Index View: 
@foreach(var customers in Model)
{
 @customers.BrithDate
}
```

I expect the output as **Friday January 1, 1990** or **1/1/1990** at least.
But the output is **1/1/1990 12:00:00 AM**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are outputting the model value directly.  If you want to use the display formatting, you should use the following helper instead.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => customers.BirthDate)
```

Here are some more details in this other question as to why.

[When should I use Html.Displayfor in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465376/when-should-i-use-html-displayfor-in-mvc)

Comment: Thanks Man! That Worked.
Can you Help me with displaying the day and month in Word format?

Comment: What is word format? if you want a full date you can try "dddd MMMM d, yyyy" as the format string

Answer (score 0):

You have to say which DataType you want to use. 
I think this should solve your problem:

```
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
 public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
```

Happy coding! :)

Comment: Thanks Man. Can you also help me with displaying the days and the month in Word format? Is it possible?

Comment: You could look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601593/how-can-i-format-07-03-2012-to-march-7th-2012-in-c-sharp

Comment: That Helped.. Thank you!
But How to include the Day as well?

Comment: Therefore there is the `DayOfWeek` property. please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.dayofweek?view=netframework-4.8